# Cannot connect to http port on Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, http, ubuntu, port

I have an Ubuntu VM running on Azure.  (Resource Manager rather than Classic)
I am running an application server on there (similar to Tomcat) that serves http on port 9001.
I created an Inbound rule to allow traffic on port 9001.
Also created an Outbound rule to allow traffic out on port 9001.

My application server is running (tested locally with curl).

When I try to test it remotely via http://:9001/somepath, the connection seems to be getting blocked.

I can successfully connect to this VM via SSH and SFTP

[update]  Here is my NSG.   This NSG is associated with the subnet of the VM.

[NSG Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdEiQ.png)

Comment: 1) this should be on serverfault. 2) you should actually show your inbound rules and your firewall rules. 3) you don't need an outbound traffic rule.

Comment: please run command `netstat -ant | grep 9001`, and post the result.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your **NSG** settings, NSG is associated with the NIC & subnet, make sure you have add port 9001 to NSG inbound rules.

Please check your Ubuntu firewall settings, make sure you have allow port 9001.
Run this command to check it, `sudo ufw status`

Also, please check your application listening on port 9001, and bound IP same as `10.0.0.4`or `0.0.0.0`, if your application bound IP address is 127.0.0.1, it will work for localhost, we can't access it from outside. To check it, please run this command `netstat -ant | grep 9001`. like:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

---

**Update**:
It is a NSG settings issue, please check your NSG settings:
1.subnet NSG, if the **subnet** associate with a NSG, we should add port 9001 to NSG inbound rules.
[image]
2.NSG settings:
[image]

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Also when I ran the ufw status command, I got:   Status: inactive

Comment: can you telnet your public IP address with port 9001?

Comment: No.  I can telnet to port 80 no problem but not port 9001.

Comment: @AlanO'Regan does your Subnet associated with NSG, we also should check this NSG settings via azure portal, make sure port 9001 added in it.

Comment: @AlanO'Regan can you show your NSG settings, we just should add port 9001 to NSG inbound rules, and we should not add outbound rules, please remove the outbound rules.

Comment: @AlanO'Regan I have update my answer about how to check NSG settings, please check it.

Comment: I updated the original question with my NSG settings (image linked).

Comment: @AlanO'Regan Please try to use `tcpdump -i eth0 dst yourclientpublicipaddess and port 9001` to capture the network traffic when you telnet this VM with port 9001. In this way, we are able to find the details.

Comment: alas no.  tcpdump yielded nothing when telnetting to 9001 so it seems it is not even getting the VM.  I am going to work through our MS support contacts to get a solution architect to take a look at this in person.  I will post my findings.  Thanks for your assistance Jason!

Comment: @AlanO'Regan Please check is there NSG associate with your `subnet`, check `virtual network`->`subnets`, check `security group`. Also we should check your local network settings, for test could you please use another network to browse it, for example, use your mobile phone network to browse it. In Azure, there are two NSGs will block it, one is NSG associate with VM, another NSG is associate with subnets, so we should mark sure there is no NSG will block it.

Comment: @AlanO'Regan Does it work now? if it solved, Could you please post your detailed solution to this issue as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.